# Как сделать переход на авторизацию вк через кнопку

Tags: java, вконтакте, button, auth

Есть код для авторизации через вк. Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку переходило на авторизацию. У меня же авторизация начинается тогда, когда запускается приложение. Пытался сделать `setOnClickListener`, но оно в итоге всё перебивало и показывало ошибку, которую даже не подсвечивали.

Вот сам код авторизации:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(fingerprints));

    login();
    VKSdk.login(this, scope);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
        }
    })) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Если надо будет - скину код самой программы.

Вот вывод через кнопку

```
public void vklogin(View view) {

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vkbut);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), VKAuth.class);
                   startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Собственно у вас явно логин запрашивается при создании активити. Вынесите его в слушатель нажатий. Если что-то с этим не получилось - покажите что именно.

Comment: Если делаю через слушатель нажатий, то не видит `int requestCode, 
int resultCode, intent data` и `super.onActivityResult`

Comment: Вилимо вы что-то не то делаете. Вам надо при нажатии вот это запустить :`VKSdk.login(this, scope);`. Также не ясно что за метод `login()` В общем очень не хватает кода чтобы понять что у вас не так конкретно.

Comment: Метод 'login' отвечает за обычную регистрацию, не через вк. Он работает нормально. `VKSdk.login(this, scope)` же отвечает за `private String[] scope = new String[]{VKScope.GROUPS, VKScope.WALL}` Сделал отдельным классом саму авторизацию, сделал вывод класса через кнопку, но всё равно почему то запуск начинается с авторизации

Comment: Что-то у вас совсем странный код. Вы в разметке повесили слушатель нажатий, который при нажатии на кнопку вешает на эту же (?) кнопку слушатель нажатий ещё один, в коем запускается какая-то непонятная активити... Тут явно всё неправильно. Наверное, имелось в виду вызвать `VKSdk.login(this, scope);`  в методе `vklogin`?

Comment: Мне именно что надо вызвать код авторизации, так как API вк обязывает это делать. `VKSdk.login(this,scope)` вроде как отображает сам текст и значение, которые указаны. Ну допустим, что мне надо именно `VKSdk.login` вызвать. Как это сделать тогда? Потому что я уже совсем как-то запутался.

Comment: VKSdk.login(this,scope) как раз и начинает логин в ВК. т.е. при нажатии надо это прописать и убрать это из onCreate

Comment: Как прописать я понял, но как убрать из onCreate это потом не очень.

Comment: Просто удалите эту строку

Comment: Тогда я всё таки не понимаю как это прописать. Мол, просто `VKSdk.login(MainActivity.this, scope);`, только в самом алгоритме нажатия?

Comment: Всё, теперь всё работает. Спасибо огромное за предоставленную помощь.

Comment: Я написал это в ответ - вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск процесса авторизации происходит вызовом

```
VKSdk.login(MainActivity.this, scope);
```

В данный момент вы вызываете эту строку при старте активити. Надо удалить её оттуда и запускать только при нажатии:

```
public void vklogin(View view) {
    VKSdk.login(MainActivity.this, scope);
}
```